# Azure: You do not have any subscriptions in the directory

Tags: azure

I have a windows account (hotmail.com) that has an associated MSDN Enterprise subscription.

I'm working for a company that has a PAYG subscription and they want to give me access so I can deploy websites, VMs etc.

They made me "co-administrator" but when I login to the portal and switch to that directory I get a "No subscriptions" notification. "You do not have access to any subscriptions in the << redacted >> directory".

In their directory I was a "User" so I thought changing that to "Global Administrator" would help. But I get the same message.

What are we missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the classic portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com), adding you as a co-administrator is enough to give you full access to the subscription.

However, in the new portal (https://portal.azure.com), you should be added as a Co-Owner through the RBAC system.
Someone with an appropriate role should go to Browse > Subscriptions > "subscription_name" > All settings > Users to add you with the Owner role for example.

Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a little bit different, I had 2 directories, both associated with the same users that got me into the error of not recognising the subscription for any directory.

I just deleted the directory I created and left the subscription associated to "the default directory" via settings in the old portal and it worked like a charm.

Comment: As long as we're necromancing old posts. one additional caveat: YOU MIGHT STILL BE GETTING CHARGED even if you have "no subscriptions".  "Subscription" or not: be sure to EXPLICITLY DELETE ANY/ALL AZURE RESOURCES as soon as you no longer need them.

Comment: Actually, you can't delete a directory if there more than one user assigned to it, so yes you have to explicitly delete all resources associated, thanks for highlighting the case

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I created a new Azure AD, when I was trying to create my first VM there I was getting the message "you don't have any subscriptions on this directory", it was not recognizing my subscription under the new AD.

To fix this, go back to the Default Directory, go to Home > Subscriptions and select your subscription, then click on the "Change Directory" tab and select the option "From Default Directory" to "New Directory"